# Append large data sets with different column number in R

Tags: r, append

I have several tables with around 8 rows and over 1 million columns in each of them. Most columns' name are the same of these different tables but some table may contain some columns while the other don't.

Now I want to append all these tables together to form one table which contains all the columns and rows of these tables. If for a certain row it doesn't contain that column in its original file, the value will be NA. And I know there are no duplicated rows in these tables.

I know I can use smartbind in library gtools to do it. But the tables are too large. When I run the smartbind, it seems the R was kept running forever and I didn't get any error msg such as out of memory.

I am not sure if I describe the problem clearly. Let's say I have two tables as following:

```
table 1:(4 rows, 1016354 columns)
ID col1  col2...  col1016343 col1016344... col1016354
1  aa    ab       zz             sz   ...      ss  
2  aa    ab       ss             zs   ...      zz 
3  ab    ab       ss             dd   ...      ss
4  ab    aa       zz             ee   ...      ss  
table 2:(3 rows, 1016343 columns)
ID col1  col2...  col1016343
5  ab    cd       dd
6  cd    ab       ee
7  cd    cd       ff
```

Now I want append them together and get the new table as:

```
ID col1  col2... col1016343  col1016344...col1016354   
1  aa    ab       zz             sz  ...       ss  
2  aa    ab       ss             zs  ...       zz 
3  ab    ab       ss             dd  ...       ss
4  ab    aa       zz             ee  ...       ss    
5  ab    cd       dd             NA  ...       NA
6  cd    ab       ee             NA  ...       NA
7  cd    cd       ff             NA  ...       NA
```

The ID is unique in each table. But ID or other columns may contain the same value in different tables but the whole row won't be exactly the same in different tables. For the different columns, it may be in the middle of the table not always at the last several columns of each table. The column name of same columns are the same.

Does anyone know an efficient way to do so?
Thank you.

Comment: Your best bet is to take the union of all the column names and to each data.frame add the columns it's missing, then `rbind` them together. `rbind` doesn't require the columns to be in the same order, it matches the names.

Comment: Thank you.Will the rbind take really long time due the size of the data set?

Comment: can't say without knowing your hardware, or what you consider a long time, but I can guarantee it won't be instantaneous. You may what to look into the `ff` or `data.table` packages.

Comment: Hi, Matthew. I tried your solution, and I used data.table.But it took several hours to merge 2 tables with about 300 rows 1 million columns in one and 96 rows and 1 million columns in the other. Sometimes, the system even killed process... I got 16G memory and I5 cpu for the PC. I can bear with merging for one hour but this is too long...